なぜ&&を書かないでよいのかわからない
本当は怖くないムーブセマンティクス
上記を読んでいると下記のコードがありました。

// 全要素値を2倍して返す関数
typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
IntVec twice_vector(IntVec a)
{
 for (auto& e : a)
   e *= 2;
 return std::move(a);  // (2)"ムーブ"で戻り値を返す
}

IntVec v = { /*...*/ };
IntVec w = twice_vector( std::move(v) );  // (1)"ムーブ"で引数へ値を渡す


関数の引数の型は move でわたって来ているので IntVec&& なのではないのかと思ったのですが、読み進めるとすぐあとに誤用パターンとして出てきました。

// 誤用パターン1
typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
IntVec twice_vector(IntVec && a)  // 引数型 = IntVec&&
{
 for (auto& e : a)
   e *= 2;
 return std::move(a);
}

IntVec v1, v2, w1, w2;
w1 = twice_vector( v1 );             // NG: コピーのシンタックスで呼び出せない！
w2 = twice_vector( std::move(v2) );  // OK: ムーブのシンタックスのみ受け付ける


似たような話は
https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/rvalue_ref_and_move_semantics.html
にも見受けられました。

C++03までは、右辺値のみを扱う右辺値参照は存在せず、右辺値はconst左辺値参照  const T&  に束縛するよう扱われていた。
このconst左辺値参照では左辺値も束縛できるため、左辺値／右辺値の区別情報が失われてしまい、右辺値のみに対して>特別な処理を記述することができなかった。
std::vector<int> v, vv;
v = vv;                  // 代入式1
v = std::vector<int>(100, 0); // 代入式2

上記コードはC++03では、代入式1,2ともに右辺は  vector<int> const&  型に束縛される。
代入処理の中では、右辺の値をコピーし、左辺の値と置き換えられる。
しかし代入式2の右辺は一時オブジェクトであり、直後に破棄されるため、一時オブジェクトをコピーすることは無駄といえる。
もし右辺値と左辺値を型を用いて区別できれば、右辺値の場合はコピーせず単に左辺と置き換えるといった処理が記述できる。
右辺値参照は、右辺値と左辺値を型として区別するために導入された。
C++11 以降では、代入式2の右辺は右辺値参照  vector<int>&&  に束縛されるため、代入演算子オーバーロードにより左辺値参照とは区別して処理される。
また、代入式2で行われる処理のことを「ムーブ」と呼ぶ。

こちらも v の型は std::vector<int> なのに、vector<int>&& 型が代入できているように読めます。
（そもそも「vector<int>&&  に束縛される」などというのはコードには明示されているようには思えず、C++の動き（仕様）を徹底的に脳内で把握していないと厳しそうです）。
なぜ上記のコードの引数の型や変数宣言に && は不要なのでしょうか？
暗黙の型変換かなにかでしょうか？　それとも暗黙の型変換は関係なく、まったくなにか別の仕組みでしょうか？（仮に暗黙の型変換だとした場合は、moveで渡している以上、勝手に型変換が起こると何がどうなるのか（ムーブじゃなくてコピーになる？）わけがわからないですが）

追記：
本質問をした際は、コンスタラクタとの対応がわかっておらず、意図が伝わっていなかった気がしてきました。
なぜコンストラクタが呼ばれるのですか？
で、実際に試した結果、下記関数には
Test Func( Test t )
{
    std::cout << "Before return from Func()\n";
    return t;   //std::move( t );
}

Test&型と Test&&型が渡って来ているといえそうです。
ということは、この関数の定義は、TypeScriptのユニオン型 (union type)のようになるのではないかと思います。強引に書くと下記です。
Test Func( Test& | Test&& t ) // `Test&` と `Test&&` の両方を受け取れる
{
    std::cout << "Before return from Func()\n";
    return t;   //std::move( t );
}

もちろんこんな風には書かないでも動いているわけ（そもそも書けないし）で、Test t で Test& t も Test && t も受け取れるというは、そう決められたということでしょうか（なんとなくそうしないとC++の歴史が長いので、過去のソースコードと互換が取れなさそうですが）？

# 別質問に回答したほうが良いのかもしれませんが呼ばれたようなので

強引に書くと下記です。

その辺が c++ 的発想になっていないというかなんというか。

IntVec twice_vector(IntVec a) { ... }

において仮引数 a は「何らかの方法で IntVec が構築（コンストラクト）できればそれでよい」のです。具体例に引きずられている様子なので別の例を挙げると
#include <iostream>

struct hoge_type {
    hoge_type() { std::cout << "default ctor @" << this << "\n"; }
    hoge_type(const hoge_type& that) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor @" << this << " from " << &that << "\n";
    }
    hoge_type(hoge_type&& that) {
        std::cout << "move ctor @" << this << " from " << &that << "\n";
    }
    hoge_type(int value) {
        std::cout << "type converting ctor @" << this << " with value " << value << "\n";
    }
};

void f(hoge_type h) { }

int main() {
    {
        std::cout << "(1)\n";
        hoge_type h;
        f(h);
    }
    {
        std::cout << "(2)\n";
        hoge_type h;
        f(std::move(h));
    }
    {
        std::cout << "(3)\n";
        f(42);
    }
}

c++03 では関数呼び出しの際に　f() の仮引数 h をコンストラクトする手段が

コピーコンストラクタ（今回避けようとしているディープコピー）
型変換コンストラクタ

c++11 以後では上記に加えて

ムーブコンストラクタ（が実装されていればムーブ可能）

オイラの例で hoge_type(hoge_type&& that) { ... } をコメントしてみると c++11 においても普通にコピーコンストラクタが呼ばれていることがわかります。
というわけで多分勘違い点は下記なのかと妄想。 void f(T a) において仮引数の型である T が

ムーブコンストラクトをサポートしていない場合には f() をどう呼ぼうが a は普通にコンストラクトされる（コピーコンストラクトであったり、型変換コンストラクトだったりする）

この場合には void f(const T& a) を自作することを考慮してもよい (c++03 の場合)
この場合には void f(T&& a) を自作することを考慮してもよい　(c++11 の場合)
void f(T a) と void f(const T& a) と void f(T&& a) を全部実装するのは怠惰の美学に反している


ムーブコンストラクトをサポートしている場合 f(a) の呼び方によって a のコンストラクトのされかたが異なる

T::T(const T&) が使われるように呼ぶと複写
T::T(T&&) が使われるように呼ぶとムーブ
void f(T&&a) をわざわざ実装しなくてよい（１手間省ける＝怠惰の美学に適合）


コピーコンストラクトとムーブコンストラクトで処理内容が異なる（ムーブコンストラクトのほうが軽い処理になる）よう実装する義務は T の作者側にあり、オイラ達 T のユーザー側はうまく使うだけでよい

T のユーザーであるオイラ達は T を使う前に次のことは知っていなければならないかもしれないです

T の複写はコスト高い（記憶域使用量ないしは時間的に）
関数の実引数として a を渡すと、複写が発生する代わりに a を引き続き利用可能
関数の実引数として std::move(a) を渡すと、 a はスコープエンドに達する前に利用できなくなる代わりに、少し処理が軽いかもしれない
なので上記２つをプログラマが意識的に使い分けてみる価値はあるかもしれない

T のユーザーであるオイラ達が T の内部について深く知りたくない場合には、何も考えずに f(a); のように複写が発生する書き方をしておけば十分です。「早すぎる最適化は諸悪の根源」です。

Disclosure: 記事「本当は怖くないムーブセマンティクス」の著者です。当該記事は「右辺値参照型に一切言及せず、ムーブセマンティクスの考え方を説明する」ことに注力しています。

なぜ&&を書かないでよいのかわからない

"誤用パターン1" の周辺説明は、意図が伝わりづらい表現になっていたかもしれません... 想定シナリオは下記の通りです：

ライブラリ提供者が右辺値参照型について正しく理解していないとき、引数にIntVec&&型をとる関数オーバーロード のみ を提供する外部仕様にしてしまうと、利用者側では通常変数を値渡し(pass-by-value)できなくなるが、おそらくそれは意図した設計ではないだろう。
（提供者が右辺値参照型を理解していなくても）引数を単にIntVec型としておけば、利用者側の判断によってコピーもしくはムーブを選択できる外部仕様を実現できる。

関数twice_vector提供側としては、下記2パターンの外部仕様が考えられます。
// IntVecのみ提供
IntVec twice_vector(IntVec);  // (a)　値型

// const IntVec&＋IntVec&&ペア提供
IntVec twice_vector(const IntVec&);  // (b1) const左辺値参照型
IntVec twice_vector(IntVec&&);       // (b2) 右辺値参照型

呼び出し側は次の通り：
// IntVecのみ提供
IntVec v1;
twice_vector(v1);             // コピー構築後に(a)が呼ばれる
twice_vector(std::move(v1));  // ムーブ構築後に(a)が呼ばれる

// const IntVec&＋IntVec&&ペア提供
IntVec v2;
twice_vector(v2);             // (b1)が呼ばれる
twice_vector(std::move(v2));  // (b2)が呼ばれる


関数引数における最適な型選択の考え方は、C++ Core Guidelines の F.15: Prefer simple and conventional ways of passing information も参考になります。
当該記事では右辺値参照型を説明していないため、同ガイドラインの「Normal parameter passing」テーブルに準拠しています。（記事執筆時点ではガイドライン存在しませんでしたので、事後で当てはめればという話ですね）
const T&＋T&&オーバーロード提供は「Advanced parameter passing」とあるように、高度な使い方といえるでしょう。ライブラリ設計意図通りであれば、T&&型引数も "誤り" ではありません（ルールF.18: For “will-move-from” parameters, pass by X&& and std::move the parameter）

FYI: 手前味噌ですが記事「参照渡し or 値渡し？」で関数引数型の選択によるオーバーヘッド比較表をまとめています。

適当にこういうの↓でも書いて実験してみたら良いのではないでしょうか．
struct Test
{
    Test(){ std::cout << "default ctor\n";  }
    Test( const Test & ){   std::cout << "copy ctor(const &)\n";    }
    Test( Test && ){    std::cout << "copy ctor(&&)\n"; }

    Test &operator=( const Test & ){    std::cout << "=(const &)\n";    return *this;   }
    Test &operator=( Test && ){ std::cout << "=(&&)\n"; return *this;   }
};

Test Func( Test t )
{
    std::cout << "Before return from Func()\n";
    return t;   //std::move( t );
}

int main()
{
    {//(1)
        std::cout << "(1)\n";
        Test t;
        t = Func( t );
    }

    {//(2)
        std::cout << "\n(2)\n";
        Test t;
        t = Func( std::move(t) );
    }

    return 0;
}

IntVec twice_vector(IntVec a) という関数が呼ばれたとき，
引数のオブジェクト a を構築する必要があるわけですが，その構築方法とは何なのか？
（↑のコードで言えば，どのctorが呼ばれるのか）
というのは呼び出し側が引数に与えた型に依るわけで，
IntVec w = twice_vector( std::move(v) );  // (1)"ムーブ"で引数へ値を渡す
ということをしているのは「引数が InitVec && な ctor で a を構築したい」から，という話でしょう．

追記：（素人なのでいろいろと言葉が正確じゃないと思うけど）
(1) コンストラクタであろうが，そうじゃないメソッド/関数 であろうが，オーバーロードが複数存在する場合，
どれが呼ばれるのかは呼び出し元が与えた引数によって決まる．（っていうのが C++ のルールであるハズ）
(2) 関数やメソッドの処理を開始するには，既述のように，まずは先に引数のオブジェクトを構築する必要がある．
オブジェクトの構築とはコンストラクタの実施により成されるのだから，つまりコンストラクタを呼ぶ（実行する）必要がある．
ここで，コンストラクタが複数ある場合には，どれを用いるのかを決めなければならないわけだが，その決定ルールとは上記の(1)である．
つまり「（暗黙的な?）コンストラクタ呼び出しにて引数として与えた物」によってどのコンストラクタが呼ばれるかが決まる．
では，ここで「引数に与えた物」とは何なのか？→っていうと，それは関数呼び出し元で引数に渡した物である．（仮引数を実引数で初期化するぜ，っていう話）
この回答内のコード例で言えば，//(1) では const T& 型の物を渡している(※)ので，コレが関数 Test Func( Test t ) の引数の t のコンストラクタ呼び出し時の引数となり，結果として，Test::Test( const Test & ) が呼ばれる．
//(2) だと std::move(t) とかいうやつを用いた結果として T&& 型の物を渡しているので，結果として，Test::Test( Test && ) が呼ばれる．
(※)：呼び出し元の記述 t = Func(t); を見ただけでは，引数に与えた物の型というのが｛ Test, Test &, const Test & ｝のどれなのかは判断付かないが，これらの候補の中で Test のコンストラクタが用意されているのは const Test & だけなので「const Test & 型を渡した」ということにされる．

戻り値の側については，私はよくわからない．
単に return a;  と書いても最近の C++ では最適化（"RVO" だの "NRVO" だのいう）でmoveになるとか何とかいう話があるみたいなのですが，言語バージョン次第だとか「実際にそうなるかどうかわからない」だとかいう感じでよくわからない世界？？

C++に不慣れで、頂いたコードを自分でゼロから書くのは難しいそうだなと感じました。実際に試すと、新しい疑問が出てしまいましたので、新しい質問を作りました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/99941/%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%a9%e3%82%af%e3%82%bf%e3%81%8c%e5%91%bc%e3%81%b0%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b

理解は深まったのですが、その過程で意図が伝わっていない（もしくはうまく言語化できていなかった）気がしてきたので、質問に追記しました。

というかむしろ発想が逆で
- std::vector 等、重い型をコピーすると性能出ないよね
- 今書きたいコードにおいてはコピーは不要であることが事前にわかっている
- 関数の引数の受け渡しの際にコピーはしたくないことをソースコード上明記するには std::move を書けばいい
という状況を明示するためにわざわざ
IntVec w = twice_vector( std::move(v) ); // v はこの後 [不要] であることを明記

としたいのです。
コピーが必要な場合にも同じ関数 twice_vector() が使いたい（同じ処理を２回書くのは無駄）わけで
IntVec w = twice_vector( v ); // v はこの後 [必要] であることを明記したい

のに twice_vector() の引数を IntVec&& にしてしまうと、後者の書き方ができなくなる＝カッコよくないっしょ？ってことで。
で、以下は @fana さんの回答につながり twice_vector(v) なる呼び出しと twice_vector(std::move(v)) なる呼び出しとで使われるコンストラクタが異なる、ってわけで。

なるほど。コピーさせたいのかムーブさせたいのか、書き分けることができることが理解できました。とはいえ、引数の型に&&を書かなくてもよいはそういうもんなんでしょうか？　@fanaさんのコードを試すとTestのコンストラクタが呼ばれてたので、あくまで&&は型情報とは関係ない（Test&&という型は存在しない、あるのはあくまでTest型のみ）ということでしょうか？

C++11 標準ライブラリが提供している型は（可能であれば）右辺値参照 T&& を受け取るようなコンストラクタなりメンバ関数なりを提供しているので、自作関数の引数が標準の型である場合にはその辺意識しなくていいよ、ってことだと。自作な型である場合には、その型に T&& なコンストラクタ等を提供しないと上記書き方できないっス。で、もし引数が T& と T&& で関数本体を書き分けなければならないとしたら、それは美徳の１つ「怠惰」に反しますよね。

理解は深まったのですが、その過程で意図が伝わっていない（もしくはうまく言語化できていなかった）気がしてきたので、質問に追記しました。

本文については他の方が十分に回答されていると思うので、主に追記に対して回答します。
Test Func(Test t) // (1) 値渡し
Test Func(Test & t) // (2) 左辺値参照渡し
Test Func(const Test & t) // (3) const左辺値参照渡し
Test Func(Test && t) // (4) 右辺値参照渡し

これらの挙動はすべて異なります。したがって、Test Func(Test t)をTest Func(Test& | Test&& t)のように解釈するのは誤りです。おそらく質問者様は、

値渡しと参照渡しの違い
左辺値・右辺値とは何か
std::moveとは何か
関数のオーバーロード解決

このあたりの理解が曖昧なために混乱しているのだと思います。これらの観点で分けてお話しします。
値渡し vs 参照渡し
まずこの観点で考えると
値渡し
Test Func(Test t) // (1) 値渡し

と参照渡し
Test Func(Test & t) // (2) 左辺値参照渡し
Test Func(const Test & t) // (3) const左辺値参照渡し
Test Func(Test && t) // (4) 右辺値参照渡し

に区別できます。
値渡しは、オブジェクトtが関数内で新規に構築されます。構築方法はTestが提供するコンストラクタとこの関数の引数の値カテゴリ（ムーブも含めたルールによって決まる）によって決定されます。後に同様の話を記述しますが、Testがコピーコンストラクタを提供しつつもムーブコンストラクタを提供しない場合、仮に引数が右辺値であってもコピーコンストラクタが呼び出されるためムーブが実際には実現されません。
一方、参照渡しはオブジェクトtを関数内で構築しません。呼び出し側で既に構築されているオブジェクトをそのまま使用します。その意味で、C言語でいうところのポインタ渡しと似ています。このため、参照渡しは値渡しと比較してオブジェクト構築にかかるリソーセスを節約できます。
左辺値・右辺値とは何か（値カテゴリ）
C++の変数（正確には式）にはTestといった型が定義されているのはご存じだと思いますが、そのほかに値カテゴリというものが存在します。ざっくり説明すると値カテゴリには左辺値(lvalue)と右辺値(rvalue)があります。正確に話すと長くなるので、気になる場合は他の文献に当たってください。
左辺値とはおおよそ名前の付く変数と文字列リテラルです。
Test t; // 名前のある変数は右辺値
"hello"; // 文字列リテラル

右辺値とはおおよそ名前の付かない値、あるいは関数の返り値（ただし左辺値参照型ではない）のことです。
1; // （文字列以外の）リテラル
Test(); // （左辺値参照型以外を返却する）関数の返り値

左辺値参照型と右辺値参照型
左辺値を参照するのが、左辺値参照型です。左辺値参照型は右辺値を参照できません。
int i;
int & j = i; // jは左辺値iを参照する左辺値参照型
// int & k = 3; // NG 左辺値参照型は右辺値を参照できない

ただし、const左辺値参照型は特別に右辺値を参照できます。
const int & k = 3; // OK

右辺値を参照するのが、右辺値参照型です。
int && i = 3; // iは右辺値3を参照する右辺値参照型

ここで値カテゴリと型を混同しないように気を付けてください。「左辺値参照型」とは型であり、「左辺値」とは値カテゴリであって別の概念です。たとえば、右辺値参照型の変数そのものは左辺値です。
int && i = 3; // iは右辺値参照型だが、i自体は名前のある変数であり値カテゴリとしては左辺値

std::moveとは何か
std::moveは左辺値を右辺値に値カテゴリを変換する効果がある関数です。"move"というからには何か複雑なことをC++はやっているように見えますが、実際のところstd::move関数は何をやっているのでしょうか？
実は、この関数は下記を戻り値にしているだけで、つまるところ右辺値参照型にキャストしているだけです。std::moveは右辺値参照型を返却する関数であるため、std::moveの結果は上述のルールに従って右辺値となります。
static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &&>(t);

拍子抜けされたかもしれませんが、std::moveは値カテゴリを右辺値にするだけであり、それ以外は何もしません。ムーブに纏わるリソースの移動は実質的にはオブジェクトのムーブコンストラクタが実行することであり、std::moveが実行するわけではありません。
関数のオーバーロード解決
さて、ここまでの話を総合してもとの話に戻ります。
Test Func(Test t) // (1) 値渡し
Test Func(Test & t) // (2) 左辺値参照渡し
Test Func(const Test & t) // (3) const左辺値参照渡し
Test Func(Test && t) // (4) 右辺値参照渡し

これらの関数のうち、どの関数が呼ばれるかは呼び出し方によって変わります。同じ呼び出し方であっても呼び出せる関数が複数該当する場合があります。その場合、優先順位が定められている場合はそれに従って決定され、優先順位が定められていない複数候補がある場合は曖昧さのためにコンパイルエラーとなります。
左辺値で呼び出す
Test t;
Func(t); // (1), (2), (3)　が呼び出し候補

const左辺値で呼び出す
const Test t;
Func(t); // (1), (3)　が呼び出し候補

右辺値で呼び出す
Test t;
Func(std::move(t)); // (1), (3), (4)が呼び出し候補

ここで注意したいのは、前述したようにconst左辺値参照型は「左辺値参照」とはいいつつも、右辺値を束縛することができます。std::moveの場合でも(3)が呼び出し候補に含まれるのはそれが理由です。
基本的には曖昧さが発生することを回避するため、上記4つがすべて宣言されることはありません。組み合わせとしては、下記が代表的かと思われます。

値渡しのみを提供する

Test Func(Test t) // (1) 値渡し


1つの定義ですべての実引数をカバーできる
参照渡しよりも値渡しのほうが好まれる場合を考慮している（たとえば組み込み型の場合は値渡しのほうが速いとされている）


const左辺値参照渡しのみを提供する

Test Func(const Test & t) // (3) const左辺値参照渡し


1つの定義ですべての実引数をカバーできる
組み込み型以外では大抵は値渡しよりも参照渡しのほうが速いと想定される
右辺値の概念はC++11から登場したため、それ以前のC++との互換性を考慮している


const左辺値参照渡しと右辺値参照渡しの2つを提供する

Test Func(const Test & t) // (3) const左辺値参照渡し
Test Func(Test && t) // (4) 右辺値参照渡し


Func関数自身がコンストラクタ、ないしは内部的にTestのコンストラクタをいずれ呼ぶことになり、実引数が右辺値の場合に（コピーコンストラクタではなく）ムーブコンストラクタを呼び出すことでリソーセスを節約できる


左辺値参照渡しのみを提供する

Test Func(Test & t) // (2) 左辺値参照渡し


仮引数tを出力変数としても扱い、実引数を関数内部で変更した結果を呼び出し元に反映することを意図している


右辺値参照渡しのみを提供する

Test Func(Test && t) // (4) 右辺値参照渡し


仮引数tのコピー処理を懸念し、ムーブセマンティクスのみを受け付ける

結論
さて、もともとのご質問に戻りますと、

Test tでTest& tもTest && tも受け取れるというは、そう決められたということでしょうか

仮引数tが構築できるのであれば、その呼び出し元での実引数の型はなんでもよいというのがC++のルールであるため、そもそも型が完全一致する必要はありません。したがって、上記で説明したように、const有無と参照かどうかを無視した型が一致すればどれでも受け取れます。（ただし、tの構築方法としてコピーコンストラクトがなく、ムーブコンストラクトしか提供していない場合は除きます）
