なぜコンストラクタが呼ばれるのですか？
試したこと
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/99939/9008
を試しました（少し std::out を足すなど自分で処理の経過がわかりやすいように追記したりしてます）。

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Test
{
   Test(){ std::cout << "default ctor\n";  }
   Test( const Test & ){   std::cout << "copy ctor(const &)\n";    }
   Test( Test && ){    std::cout << "copy ctor(&&)\n"; }

   Test &operator=( const Test & ){    std::cout << "=(const &)\n";    return *this;   }
   Test &operator=( Test && ){ std::cout << "=(&&)\n"; return *this;   }
};

Test Func( Test t )
{
   std::cout << "Before return from Func()\n";
   return t;   //std::move( t );
}

int main()
{
   {//(1)
       std::cout << "(1)\n";
       Test t;
       std::cout << "Func呼び出す\n";
       t = Func( t );
   }

   {//(2)
       std::cout << "\n(2)\n";
       Test t;
       std::cout << "Func呼び出す\n";
       t = Func( std::move(t) );
   }

   return 0;
}


結果：
(1)
default ctor
Func呼び出す
copy ctor(const &)
Before return from Func()
copy ctor(&&)
=(&&)

(2)
default ctor
Func呼び出す
copy ctor(&&)
Before return from Func()
copy ctor(&&)
=(&&)

気になる箇所
copy ctor(&&) が表示されているということは、Test( Test && ){    std::cout << "copy ctor(&&)\n"; } のコンストラクタが実行されているということですよね(?)
ムーブは、ポインターの付替えであって、メモリの確保は起こらないと考えていたのですが、コンストラクタが呼ばれるのが不思議に思います。コンストラクタというのはオブジェクトが作られたとき（つまりメモリが確保されたとき）に実行されるものなのだと考えているので、ポインターの付替えだとメモリは確保されない（別の言い方をするとコピーされない）ので、コンストラクタは呼ばれないものと思ったのですが... なぜコンストラクタ呼ばれるのでしょうか？　そもそもムーブやメモリ確保について誤解をしていますでしょうか？

※かなりどうでもいい話ですが，"copy ctor(&&)\n" というところは "move ctor(&&)\n" と書くべきだったな…と．Sorryです．

ある型に関しての「ムーブという処理」の具体的な実装というのが

ポインターの付替え

になるかもしれませんが，それはそれであり，とりあえず別の話です．

std::move(t) というのがそこで何かそういう処理をしているわけではなくて，
これは単に t を「右辺値」とかいう物にキャスト(?)するだけの物です．
で，そのキャスト(?)を行う理由というのは，このコード例で言えば
「Test( const Test & ) ではなくて Test( Test && ) の側を呼ばせるため」です．
※このコード例だと Test 型は何のデータも持っていませんが，
仮に何かしらの「ムーブという処理をすべきデータ」を抱えているとしたら，
そのデータに関する「ムーブという処理」の具体的な実装（ポインタの付け替えとか）というのをこの Test( Test && ) に実装するわけです．

ムーブはコピーと同じく値の生成はされます。 ただ、そのときに元の内容を効率的に再利用できる可能性があるので「ムーブの文脈である」ということが区別できるようになっているだけです。
ムーブのときにどのような形で処理すれば効率的なのかはそのクラスがどのような定義になっているか次第なのでどうやって効率が実現されるかは言語として関知しません。 典型的な方法としてオブジェクト内部で持っているポインタを交換するというやり方があるだけで、それが言語としての決まりというわけではありません。

int f(int x) { return x+1; }

という関数を書いたとしたら f(int) の呼び出し側の実引数と f(int) の中の x とは別変数です。この際には必ずコピーをしなければなりません。同様 x+1 は prvalue であり f(int) の呼び出し側はこの値を複写しなければ使うことができません。
なので関数引数や返却値に（他言語 c# でいう値型）を使う場合には必ずコピーが必要となります＝コンストラクタが必要。実際の処理においては rax レジスタから r9 レジスタに mov するだけなのかもしれませんが。
std::move 系がコピーするだのしないだの、うだうだ言っているのは同様他言語でいう参照型の「参照されている本体」のほうです。
std::vector<int> な自動変数であれば２つの別メモリ領域が使われ
- スタック上に置かれるであろう管理領域
- ヒープ上に置かれるであろうデータ本体
右辺値参照だとか std::move だとか、この質問での議題であるところの引数が (T&&) であるコンストラクタとかは
- データ本体は一切いじらずに
- 管理領域をコピーしたり破棄したりすることでデータ本体の所有権とかその辺を切り替える
のが目的です。なのでやはりコンストラクタやデストラクタは、右辺値参照の所有権移動処理の際に呼ばれていることになります。質問にある単語を使えば、
- 右辺値参照を引数に持つコンストラクタはポインタの付け替えを行う（シャローコピー相当）
- 左辺値を引数に持つコンストラクタはポインタが指す先の値の塊まで完全複写を行う（ディープコピー相当）
